# Limit of a sequence of intervals

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, interval-arithmetic

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\geqslant 1} $ be a sequence such that $a_n>0\ \forall n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ . What will be

> $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a_n,1) \ \ =?$$

Will it be $(0,1)$ or $[0,1)$ ?

Edit:

This was originally a part of a larger question.

> Consider $2$ sequences $\{a_n\}\ \&\ \{b_n\}$ with $a_n>0$ and $b_n>1$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$. Define $A_n=[a_n,b_n)$. Find $\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n$

Can someone confirm me whether both the answers are $(0,1)$ or not?

Comment: It's $(0,1)$ because $0$ does not belong to any of the intervals.

Comment: $(0,1)$, since for no $n$ does $0$ belong to $[a_n,1)$.

Comment: @Crostul Sorry for wrongly pressing the return button . Please check my complete question.

Comment: @EvanAad Sorry for wrongly pressing the return button . Please check my complete question.

Comment: $\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n) = \lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n) = (0,1]$.

Comment: @EvanAad Kindly provide a complete answer to my question. As you may see , I have got it wrong , so I need to see the steps. I prefer to use the union-intersection definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

Comment: In this case, both $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ coincide with $(0,1]$ (I suppose that you write $b_n > 1$, so that $1$ belongs to all intervals).

Comment: You mean $b_n>1$ as you have it or $b_n<1$?

Comment: @JimmyR. Question is correct.

Comment: OP, if there's anything unclear with my answer, let me know and I'll explain. Otherwise, please consider clicking the check mark next to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @EvanAad I came in minutees ago, and was understanding. Once done, I did what was to be done on my part. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show that
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n) = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n) = (0,1].
$$

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

By definition of $\liminf$, $x \in \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n)$ iff $x$ belongs to every interval $[a_n,b_n)$ for sufficiently big $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$. I claim that this is the case iff $x \in (0,1]$. To see this, suppose firstly that $x \in (0,1]$. Then, since $b_n > 1$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, we have for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ that $x < b_n$. At the same time, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = 0$, then, for sufficiently big $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, we have that $a_n \leq x$. Therefore, for sufficiently big $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, $x \in [a_n, b_n)$. Conversely, if $x \in [a_n, b_n)$ for all sufficiently big $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, then, on the one hand, $x$ must be greater than $0$, since $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, while, on the other hand, $x$ cannot be greater than $1$, because otherwise, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n = 1$, then, for sufficiently big $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, we would have $b_n < x$, implying that $x \notin [a_n, b_n)$.

The previous paragraph established that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n) = (0,1]$. Since it is always the case that $\liminf \subseteq \limsup$, we automatically have $(0,1] \subseteq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n)$. It remains to show that $(0,1] \supseteq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n)$. Indeed, suppose that $x \in \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}[a_n,b_n)$. Then, by definition of $\limsup$, $x$ belongs to infinitely many intervals $[a_n,b_n)$. Therefore, since $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, we must have $x > 0$. To see that $x \leq 1$, assume the contrary. Then, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n = 1$, we have for *all* sufficiently big $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, that $b_n < x$. But this contradicts the fact that for infinitely many $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ we have $x \in [a_n, b_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(0,1)$ obviously because $\forall n,\, 0\notin [a_n,1)$ is a consequence of $\forall n,\, a_n\gt 0$.

Comment: Sorry for wrongly pressing the return button . Please check my complete question.